# Convertir pyodbc.cursor a formatos int u otros

Tags: python, sql

Tengo este codigo

```
def Read(conn):
    Filas = conn.execute("select count (*) from Compras")
    print(Filas)

Read(conn)
```

y obtengo este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual en SQL Server representa la cantidad de filas que tengo.
Como puedo convertirlo a int? y en general como convertir ese tipo de resultados a los formatos que desee?

Answer (score 1):

Estás retornando una instancia de [`pyodbc.Cursor`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor), el cual es un objeto que representa un cursor de la base de datos y que dispone de múltiples métodos para obtener las filas de la consulta:

- **`cursor.fetchval()`**: retorna el primer valor de la primera fila de la consulta. En tu caso la consulta retorna algo como `[(13, )]`, es decir una sola fila con un solo valor, por lo que este método es tu opción más simple:

  ```
  filas = Read(conn).fetchval()
  print(filas)
  ```

  > 13

  obviamente puedes hacer que la función retorne el valor directamente:

  ```
  def read(conn):
      cursor = conn.execute("select count (*) from Compras")
      filas = cursor.fetchval()
      return filas

  print(read(conn))
  ```

  > **Nota**: en Python es buena práctica de estilo nombrar a las funciones / métodos en minúscula usnado `_` para separar palabras, dejando CamelCase para las clases:
  >
  > ```
  > class SoyUnaClase:
  >     pass
  >
  > def soy_una_funcion():
  >     pass
  > ```
  >
  > ver [Guía de estilo para el código Python, PEP-8 en Español](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf).
- **El cursor en si mismo es iterable** (comportándose de forma similar a un generador), lo cual es muy útil si vamos a procesar fila a fila y queremos preservar memoria:

  ```
  db = pyodbc.connect("...")
  cur = db.execute("select * from Usuarios")

  for row in cur:
      print(row)
  ```

  > ```
  > (1, "Raúl", 'Aguilera', 'raul@foomail.com')    
  > (2, "Ana", 'Morón', 'ana@foomail.com')    
  > (3, "Pedro", 'García', 'pedro@foomail.com')
  > ```

  también puedes usar el nombre de la columna para obtener el valor de cada una:

  ```
  db = pyodbc.connect(...)
  cur = db.execute("select * from Usuarios")

  for row in cur:
      print(row.id)
      print(row.nombre)
      print(row.apellido)
      print(row.email)
      print()
  ```

  > 1
  >   Raúl
  >   Aguilera
  >   raul@foomail.com
  >
  > 2
  >   Ana
  >   Morón
  >   ana@foomail.com
  >
  > 3
  >   Pedro
  >   García
  >   Pedro@foomail.com
- **`cursor.fetchone()`**: obtiene una sola fila cada vez que es llamado:

  ```
  db = pyodbc.connect("...")
  cur = db.execute("select * from Usuarios")
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> cur.fetchone()    
  > (1, "Raúl", 'Aguilera', 'raul@foomail.com')    
  > >>> cur.fetchone()    
  > (2, "Ana", 'Morón', 'ana@foomail.com')
  > ```

  En ausencia del método `fetchval`, usar `fetchone` es una opción simple en tu caso también:

  ```
  conn.execute("select count (*) from Compras")
  filas = cursor.fetchone()[0]
  ```
- **`cursor.fetchmany(size=n)`**: retorna una lista con las siguientes `n` filas cada vez que es llamado:

  ```
  db = pyodbc.connect("...")
  cur = db.execute("select * from Usuarios")
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> cur.fetchmany(2)
  > [(1, "Raúl", 'Aguilera', 'raul@foomail.com'),
  >  (2, "Ana", 'Morón', 'ana@foomail.com')]
  > >>> cur.fetchmany(2)
  > [(3, "Pedro", 'García', 'pedro@foomail.com')]
  > ```
- **`cursos.fetchall()`**: retorna todas las filas restantes en una lista:

  ```
  db = pyodbc.connect(con_str)
  cur = db.execute("select * from pedidos")
  print(cur.fetchall())
  ```

  > ```
  > [(1, "Raúl", 'Aguilera', 'raul@foomail.com'),    
  >  (2, "Ana", 'Morón', 'ana@foomail.com'),    
  >  (3, "Pedro", 'García', 'pedro@foomail.com')]
  > ```

El tipo de cada dato es convertido al tipo correspondiente de Python automáticamente (`int`, `float`, `str`, `datetime.datetime`, etc). Por norma general no tienes que preocuparte por esto.